# Export Database From Oracle to MSAccess

Tags: .net, oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

my database is in oracle and  i am using oracle sql developer ,
 i want to export my database to ms access.please tell me if there is any opens source tool or any inbuilt feature of oracle sql developer which help in migration of my db form oracle to ms access then please suggest.share link if so
Thanks in advance